# tag cleanup: [editor]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I was looking for an example for my question on tag definitions and came across [editor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/editor), which isn't the best example because it obviously needs tag cleanup.  So this is a tag cleanup request.  In order of usage, this is one of the first undefined tags (122 questions).
It appears that a majority of the questions are actually off-topic and weren't closed (requests for software recommendations).  The remainder include:

- how to accomplish specific tasks with specific editors
- how to change the default editor in an application
- system questions related to editors (like implications of temporary files)
- how to edit specific kinds of files
- how to edit meta data or content held in memory
- feature differences between editors
- image editing
- sound editing
- font editing

Some of these don't benefit from including the tag and the tag could be dropped.  [image-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-editing) and [sound-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound-editing) already exist and there are a number of font-related tags that font editing could fit under.  I didn't do an exhaustive cross-reference, but at least some of the specific editors have their own tags and tags could be created for ones that don't.  Changing the default editor could be tagged with the application the question refers to.  Most common filetypes have a tag and editing a filetype could just be tagged with the filetype.  The same would apply to editing things other than files.  Recommendation: drop the [editor] tag and retag the questions.

Comment: Software recs *were* ontopic when those questions were asked I suspect.

Comment: As requested: copying my comment from the 'Basis for defining tags' meta: I'm saying tags like [editor] shouldn't exist, and should be removed if they do. If people are having problems with a specific editor they should use a tag for that specific editor. "How do I edit 'x'" should be tagged with the platform, (as the answer will differ from platform to platform), and with other related tags as necessary (file permissions, editing read-only files, editing specific file types like PDF etc). I'm not sure that "status of editor 'x'" is on topic, but if it is, it should be tagged with that editor.